# Unable to get aws-iam-authenticator in config-map while applying through AWS CodeBuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks

I am making CICD pipeline, using AWS CodeBuild to build and deploy application(service) to aws eks cluster. I have installed kubectl and aws-iam-authenticator properly,
getting **aws instead of aws-iam-authenticator in command**

```
kind: Config 
preferences: {} 
users: 
- name: arn:aws:eks:ap-south-1:*******:cluster/DevCluster 
user: 
exec: 
apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1 
args: 
- eks 
- get-token 
- --cluster-name 
- DevCluster
```

**command: aws**

env: null

[Container] 2019/05/14 04:32:09 Running command kubectl get svc 
**error: the server doesn't have a resource type "svc"**

**I donot want to edit configmap manually because it comes through pipeline.**

Comment: Does your pipeline incorporate similar command before you are trying to use kubectl ?:
'aws eks --region eu-west-2 update-kubeconfig --name DevCluster'

Comment: Yes , I have applied above commands before use kubectl. I am getting same error.

Comment: I got an answer. I resolved it.

Comment: Can you please share the fixture with the others in form of answer.

Comment: Sure. There is  no issue with configmap file.Its all right. 1) I need to make Cloudformation (cluster+nodeinstance)**trusted role** to communicate with Codebuild by editing trusted role.  2) Need to add usedata section to communicate node instance with clusters.

Answer (score 1):

As @Priya Rani said in the comments, he found the solution.

There is no issue with configmap file. Its all right.

1) I need to make Cloudformation (cluster+nodeinstance)**trusted role** to communicate with Codebuild by editing trusted role.

2) Need to add usedata section to communicate node instance with clusters.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't just load a proper/dedicated kube config file, by setting KUBECONFIG env variable inside your CICD pipeline, like this:

```
export KUBECONFIG=$KUBECONFIG:~/.kube/config-devel
```

which would include a right command to use with **aws-iam-authenticator**:

```
#
#config-devel
#
...
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: aws
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      command: aws-iam-authenticator
      args:
        - "token"
        - "-i"
        - "<cluster-name>"
```